# Panda dataframe not updating all columns

Tags: python

I am running the following test code to map violations to nearby buildingIDs by "NearVicinity" and "MidVicinity".  The results come out unexpected and I am not sure what I am missing in my code.

So the results I get seem to have correctly updated 'TicketIssuedDT' and 'NearVicinity', 'MidVicinity' colunns however the 'BuildingID' and 'X' columns only map correctly to result['X'][0] and result['BuildingID'][0].  All remaining 999 rows have 0 for 'BuildingID' and 'X'.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1000, 5)),columns=['BuildingID', 'TicketIssuedDT', 'NearVicinity', 'MidVicinity','X'])

z = 0    
for i in range(0,10):
#for i, j in dataframe2.iterrows(): 
    dataframe2Lat = dataframe2['Latitude'][i]
    dataframe2Long = dataframe2['Longitude'][i]

    for x in range(0,11102):
    #for x, y in dataframe1.iterrows():
        dist = (math.fabs(dataframe2Long - dataframe1['Longitude'][x]) + math.fabs(dataframe2Lat - dataframe1['Latitude'][x]))
        if dist < .02:
            result['X'][z] = x
            result['BuildingID'][z] = dataframe1['BuildingID'][x]
            result['TicketIssuedDT'][z] = dataframe2['TicketIssuedDT'][i]
            result['MidVicinity'][z] = 1
            if dist < .007:
                result['NearVicinity'][z] = 1
            else:
                result['NearVicinity'][z] = 0
            z += 1  
    print(i)
```

Comment: It looks like the indentation for 'z += 1' is wrong. As is, z will stop increasing as soon as a distance is found that is greater than 0.02.

Comment: I relooked at the indentation and it is as intended as I only want z to update and add a new row if there is a match for MidVicinity.  What is odd is that the result['MidVicinity']  result['NearVicinity'] and result['TicketIssuedDT'][z] do appear to update properly based on z getting incremented.  It is only result['X'] and result['BuildingID'] that do not properly update.  And it appears the code is properly capturing dataframe1['Longitude'][x] and dataframe1['Latitude'][x] to calculate dist.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear about the intent of your code. Incrementing z only when you find a result only works if you know in advance that there are less than 1,000 results. It looks like you're checking 11x that many records, so...

Comment: Thanks Sohier.  I forgot to update the results dataframe to more rows because you are correct it does capture more than 1000 results.  However, even after doing that result['X'][z] and result['BuildingID'][z] do not update while result['MidVicinity'] result['NearVicinity'] and result['TicketIssuedDT'][z] do properly update.